# re.sub() ellipsis in Python 3

Tags: regex, python-3.x

I need a simple solution, but it's evading me. I am passing a list of strings to a for loop for some cleaning up, and need to remove any instance of an ellipsis. Here's an example of what I've tried:

```
text_list = ["string1", "string2", "string3...", "string.4"]
for i in range(len(text_list)):
    text_list[i] = re.sub("\.", "", text_list[i])
    text_list[i] = re.sub("\.{3}", "", text_list[i])
    text_list[i] = re.sub("\.\.\.", "", text_list[i])
```

Naturally, none of these removes an ellipsis. The period is removed, though. So my output would be:

```
for text in text_list:
    print(text)

>>>string1
   string2
   string3...   <- THIS ONE DIDN'T CHANGE
   string4      <- BUT THIS ONE DID
```

I've exhausted my regex documentation and Google searches. How do I match an ellipsis with a regex?

Comment: Why does it have to be a regex? Can't you just use regular string replacing (`text_list[i] = text_list[i].replace('...', '')`)?

Comment: Your code works for me....

Comment: This should work. I copied this code and tried it on my laptop. It works. As @rickdenhaan suggests, using the replace method is a simpler solution. `>>> re.sub("\.","","string3....")
'string3'`

Comment: If you want to remove an actual ellipsis, as in the unicode HORIZONTAL ELLIPSIS character (`…`), then you need to use that in the code, since 3 periods won't match it.

Comment: I'm actually attempting to clean a collection of tweets for analysis, and it was failing to pick up the ellipsis since it is encoded differently than just "...".swalladge, your thought on using the unicode was exactly right. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@swalladge had the right notion here: use unicode. Here is his answer.

"If you want to remove an actual ellipsis, as in the unicode HORIZONTAL ELLIPSIS character (…), then you need to use that in the code, since 3 periods won't match it." –@swalladge

@rickdenhaan also had an easier way to accomplish the task. Thanks!